# Finding the exponential form of $z=1+i\sqrt{3}$ and $z=1+\cos{a}+i\sin{a}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is what I have been able to accomplish:

For the first one I found that $|z|=z\bar{z}=2$ and $\theta=\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\pi}{3}$.  So we get $2e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i}$.

For the second one I have only been able to solve the following: $|z|=\sqrt{1+2\cos{a}}$.  I'm stuck on how to treat the trig functions when converting to exponential form.

Comment: Why do you compute $|z|-z \bar z$? Shouldn't you just compute $|z|$ or $\sqrt{z \bar z}$?

Comment: I believe your second modulus should be $ \ \sqrt{2 + 2 \cos a} \ $ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1+i\sqrt{3}=2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+i\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=2\left(\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{3}}+i\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{3}} \right)=2e^{{i\tfrac{\pi}{3}}}$$
The second expression is
$$z=1+\cos{\alpha}+i\sin{\alpha}=2\cos^2{\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}+2i\sin{\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{\alpha}{2}} \\ 
=2\cos{\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}\left(\cos{\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}+i\sin{\dfrac{\alpha}{2}} \right)=2\cos{\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot e^{i{\tfrac{\alpha}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 3):

$z=2(\cos \pi/3+i\sin \pi/3)=2e^{i\pi/3}$

Next one $z=2\cos (a/2)(\cos a/2+i\sin a/2)=2\cos (a/2)e^{ia/2}$

Answer (score 1):

For your second $ \ z \ $, you will find the trig identities

$$\tan ( \frac{\theta}{2} ) \ = \ \frac{\sin \theta}{1 \ + \ \cos \theta} $$

and

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot (1 + \cos 2 \theta) \ = \ \cos^2 \theta \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot (1 + \cos  \theta) \ = \ \cos^2 (\frac{\theta}{2})$$

useful...